# How to determine whether axis will hide labels or not

Tags: r

`?axis` says

> The code tries hard not to draw overlapping tick labels, and so will omit labels where they would abut or overlap previously drawn labels. This can result in, for example, every other tick being labelled. (The ticks are drawn left to right or bottom to top, and space at least the size of an ‘m’ is left between labels.)

I am working with a given vector of tickmarks for the x-axis and the vector of corresponding labels:

```
axis(1,at=tickmarks,labels=ticklabels,cex.axis=labelcex)
```

I would like to rotate the labels 90 degrees if they cannot fit in horizontally (i.e. if making them horizontal means that any of them will have to be hidden.)

Is there a way to determine whether `axis` is going to hide (or has hidden) any labels, for a given axis length, `tickmarks`, `ticklabels`, and `labelcex`?

Comment: Can't you plot the graph and look? You could always split the ticks between axis 1 and 3

Comment: @rawr The plots are generated automatically as part of an interactive report system. Over time, there will be tens of thousands of these plots plotted. I'm already using both axes 1 and 3.